# Convert Boolean to char

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("TransID");
var dr = dataTable.NewRow();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   dataTable.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i][1]);                   
   vRFCStructure.SetValue("BARCODE", dt.Rows[i][0]);
   vRFCStructure.SetValue("STATUS", Convert.ToChar(dt.Rows[i][1]));
   vRFCStructure.SetValue("MBLNR", " ");
}
```

This is my code. I am getting boolean value from the data table in `dt.Rows[i][1]`. I need to send the bool value as 0 and 1 to another table as `char`.

I tried  `Convert.ToChar` but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you get any exception when using `Convert.ToChar`?

Comment: error as String must be exactly one character long.

Comment: THIS WAS THE EXCEPTION  which i got when i used Convert.ToChar

Comment: @SanthoshRaja if that is the exception, then does it contain an actual Boolean or a string with the value "True" or "False"?

Comment: Convert.ToChar( bool ) always throw InvalidCastException. It is not supported. https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dt6c6b1f(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to simply do like this:

```
vRFCStructure.SetValue("STATUS", ((bool)dt.Rows[i][1]) ? '1' : '0');
```

First cast it to `bool`. Then return `1` or `0` depending on bool value. If the column is `null` it will break.

As [fubo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315444/fubo) mentioned, you can add support for nullable bool as well:

```
vRFCStructure.SetValue("STATUS", ((bool?)dt.Rows[i][1]) == true ? '1' : '0');
```

If the column is null, it should return `0`.

Comment: @SanthoshRaja - No problem. It may not be the most elegant solution, but it should work as long as the column isn't `null`.

Comment: in case of nullable you can do `(bool?)dt.Rows[i][1]) == true ? '1' : '0'` so `null` and `false` result into `0`

Comment: Thank you @fubo. I've improved the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: @SanthoshRaja you should accept the answer by clicking the green check mark if this one helped you solving your problem